# Ultima 6 Clue to clean shrines with the runes

Tags: ultima-6

I'm trying to figure out how i can free the shrines from the gargoyles

### 1 British's quest to free the shrines

after fighting the gargoyles, i talked with British and he send me to a quest to free the shrines. He told me to ask Geoffrey for further details.

### 2 Geoffrey and the Guards

Geoffrey told me that a group of guards went to free the shrine of compassion. they failed and i should talk to a wounded warrior in Cove, his name would be Gertan.

### 3 Gertan and the force field

Gertan in Cove told me they failed because the gargoyles use foul magic, a **force field** prevents them from freeing the shrines.

### Question

**how do i know that i have to use the Runes and the Mantra to clean the shrines?** - no one told me to do that so far! as well, no one told me that the mayor knows who has the rune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the general intended flow of the quest is like this:

- travel to Cove and find the wounded soldiers resting ad the healer hut.
- talk to Gertan who only tells you about the field
- ask around the city
- find the mayor of the city, Viscount Ahrmaand.

Ask him about Gertan thou shalt:

> "A party of adventurers came here after their attempt to defeat the gargoyles at the Shrine of Compassion."
> "I spoke with their leader when they arrived."
> "Thou shouldst speak with him thyself. He told of a strange violet energy field."
> "I think mayhap 'tis similar to the force which blocked entry to the shrines many years ago."
> "The eight mystic runes were most useful in those days."

About the runes shalt thee continue:

> "Use the Rune of Compassion whilst chanting the Mantra of Compassion."
> "Methinks this may negate the gargoyle's magic at that shrine."

And finally, asking about the Mantra shalt send thou back where thou cometh from.

> "Ask Lord British's Chancellor, Tholden."
> "He canst tell thee of the mantra, and like as not he will also know of the rune."

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you very very much - that was the clue!!!! very very nice thanks! i never found out on my own, i "just used the rune without knowing why"

Comment: @MartinFrank well, at least you didn't had to ask to Iolo's horse Smith in the next game...

Comment: i remember Smith and i don't recall any positive Memories ^^ *laughter*

Comment: @MartinFrank see the positive side. He is not Chuckles.

Comment: give that cannon, Chuckles on my list... *you are funny*